# Why the gradient of categorical crossentropy loss with respect to logits is 0 with gradient tape in TF2.0?

Tags: tensorflow, gradient

I am learning Tensorflow 2.0 and I am trying to figure out how Gradient Tapes work. I have this simple example, in which, I evaluate the cross entropy loss between logits and labels. I am wondering why the gradients with respect to logits is being zero. (Please look at the code below).
The version of TF is tensorflow-gpu==2.0.0-rc0.

```py
logits = tf.Variable([[1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0]], type=tf.float32)
labels = tf.constant([[1, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0], [0, 0, 1]],dtype=tf.float32)
with tf.GradientTape(persistent=True) as tape:
    loss = tf.reduce_sum(tf.losses.categorical_crossentropy(labels, logits))

grads = tape.gradient(loss, logits)
print(grads)
```

I am getting

```
 tf.Tensor(
[[0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0.]], shape=(3, 3), dtype=float32)
```

as a result, but should not it tell me how much should I change logits in order to minimize the loss?

Answer (score 0):

When calculate the cross entropy loss, set `from_logits=True` in the `tf.losses.categorical_crossentropy()`. In default, it's false, which means you are directly calculate the cross entropy loss using `-p*log(q)`. By setting the `from_logits=True`, you are using `-p*log(softmax(q))` to calculate the loss.

Update:

Just find one interesting results.

```py
logits = tf.Variable([[0.8, 0.1, 0.1]], dtype=tf.float32)
labels = tf.constant([[1, 0, 0]],dtype=tf.float32)

with tf.GradientTape(persistent=True) as tape:
    loss = tf.reduce_sum(tf.keras.losses.categorical_crossentropy(labels, logits, from_logits=False))

grads = tape.gradient(loss, logits)
print(grads)
```

The grads will be `tf.Tensor([[-0.25  1.    1.  ]], shape=(1, 3), dtype=float32)`

Previously, I thought tensorflow will use `loss=-\Sigma_i(p_i)\log(q_i)` to calculate the loss, and if we derive on `q_i`, we will have the derivative be `-p_i/q_i`. So, the expected grads should be `[-1.25, 0, 0]`. But the output grads looks like all increased by 1. But it won't affect the optimization process.

For now, I'm still trying to figure out why the grads will be increased by one. After reading the source code of [tf.categorical_crossentropy](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/f03fe1bf795061408fafda9704c485aea7bddde2/tensorflow/python/keras/backend.py#L4351), I found that even though we set `from_logits=False`, it still normalize the probabilities. That will change the final gradient expression. Specifically, the gradient will be `-p_i/q_i+p_i/sum_j(q_j)`. If `p_i=1` and `sum_j(q_j)=1`, the final gradient will plus one. That's why the gradient will be `-0.25`, however, I haven't figured out why the last two gradients would be `1.`.

To prove that all gradients are increased by `1/sum_j(q_j)`,

```py
logits = tf.Variable([[0.5, 0.1, 0.1]], dtype=tf.float32)
labels = tf.constant([[1, 0, 0]],dtype=tf.float32)

with tf.GradientTape(persistent=True) as tape:
    loss = tf.reduce_sum(tf.keras.losses.categorical_crossentropy(labels, logits, from_logits=False))

grads = tape.gradient(loss, logits)
print(grads)
```

The grads are `tf.Tensor([[-0.57142866  1.4285713   1.4285713 ]]`, which should be `[-2,0,0]`.

It shows that all gradients are increased by `1/(0.5+0.1+0.1)`. For the `p_i==1`, the gradient increased by `1/(0.5+0.1+0.1)` makes sense to me. But I don't understand why `p_i==0`, the gradient is still increased by `1/(0.5+0.1+0.1)`.

Comment: Thank you. I noticed that this way it works. However, why should not ```from_logits=False``` still work?

Comment: Hi @Siavash, please check my updates. I'm still trying to figure out this weird behavior.

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured that.

The keras categorical cross entropy calculates the gradient using the following way:

```
sum(target) / sum(input) - target / input
```

You just sum the values for both targets and inputs ONLY if the input(i) is different from ZERO.