# Why are gradients incorrect for categorical crossentropy?

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning

After answering [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57892492/why-the-gradient-of-categorical-crossentropy-loss-with-respect-to-logits-is-0-wi/57894760#57894760), there are some interesting but confused findings I met in tensorflow 2.0. The gradients of `logits` looks incorrect to me. Let's say we have `logits` and `labels` here.

```py
logits = tf.Variable([[0.8, 0.1, 0.1]], dtype=tf.float32)
labels = tf.constant([[1, 0, 0]],dtype=tf.float32)

with tf.GradientTape(persistent=True) as tape:
    loss = tf.reduce_sum(tf.keras.losses.categorical_crossentropy(labels, logits, 
                                                                  from_logits=False))
grads = tape.gradient(loss, logits)
print(grads)
```

Since `logits` is already a prob distribution, so I set `from_logits=False` in the loss function.

I thought tensorflow will use `loss=-\Sigma_i(p_i)\log(q_i)` to calculate the loss, and if we derive on `q_i`, we will have the derivative be `-p_i/q_i`. So, the expected grads should be [-1.25,0,0]. However, tensorflow will return [-0.25,1,1].

After reading the source code of [`tf.categorical_crossentropy`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/f03fe1bf795061408fafda9704c485aea7bddde2/tensorflow/python/keras/backend.py#L4351), I found that even though we set `from_logits=False`, it still normalize the probabilities. That will change the final gradient expression. Specifically, the gradient will be `-p_i/q_i+p_i/sum_j(q_j)`. If `p_i=1` and `sum_j(q_j)=1`, the final gradient will plus one. That's why the gradient will be -0.25, however, I haven't figured out why the last two gradients would be 1.

To prove that all gradients are increased by `1/sum_j(q_j)`, I made up a logits, which is not prob distribution, and set `from_logits=False` still.

```py
logits = tf.Variable([[0.5, 0.1, 0.1]], dtype=tf.float32)
labels = tf.constant([[1, 0, 0]],dtype=tf.float32)

with tf.GradientTape(persistent=True) as tape:
    loss = tf.reduce_sum(tf.keras.losses.categorical_crossentropy(labels, logits,
                                                                  from_logits=False))
grads = tape.gradient(loss, logits)
print(grads)
```

The grads returned by tensorflow is `[-0.57142866,1.4285713,1.4285713 ]`, which I thought should be `[-2,0,0]`.

It shows that all gradients are increased by `1/(0.5+0.1+0.1)`. For the `p_i==1`, the gradient increased by `1/(0.5+0.1+0.1)` makes sense to me. But I don't understand why `p_i==0`, the gradient is still increased by `1/(0.5+0.1+0.1)`.

**Update**

Thanks for @OverLordGoldDragon's kind reminder. After normalizing the probs, the correct gradients formula should be `-p_i/q_i+1/sum_j(q_j)`. So the behaviors in the question are expected.

Comment: Interesting question; is an answer still needed?

Comment: Yes, please! I haven't figured it out yet.

Comment: Question: is `-p_i/q_i+p_i/sum_j(q_j)` derived by you, or taken from text? Asking as I don't actually know the "formula" for the gradient - I have my own derivation that works, but it appears to contradict yours

Comment: You're right! I derived again and the formula should be `-p_i/q_i+1/sum_j(q_j)`, which means each gradient will be increased by `1/sum_j(q_j)`. Thanks! I guess I missed one of `sum` over `p` when I asked this question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Categorical crossentropy is tricky, particularly w.r.t. one-hot encodings; the problem arises out of presuming that some predictions are "tossed out" in computing loss or gradient, when looking at how loss is computed:

`loss = f(labels * preds) = f([1, 0, 0] * preds)`

**Why are the gradients incorrect?** Above may suggest that `preds[1:]` don't matter, but note that this isn't actually *preds* - it's `preds_normalized`, which involves single element of `preds`. To get a better idea of what's happening, the [Numpy backend](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/985521ee7050df39f9c06f53b54e17927bd1e6ea/keras/backend/numpy_backend.py#L333) is helpful; assuming `from_logits=False`:

```py
losses = []
for label, pred in zip(labels, preds):
    pred_norm = pred / pred.sum(axis=-1, keepdims=True)
    losses.append(np.sum(label * -np.log(pred_norm), axis=-1, keepdims=False))
```

A more complete explanation of above - [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58159154/how-to-calculate-categorical-cross-entropy-by-hand/58160633#58160633). Below is my derivation of the gradients formula, with examples comparing its Numpy implementation with `tf.GradientTape` results. To skip the meaty details, scroll to "Main idea".

---

**Formula + Derivation**: proof of correctness at the bottom.

```py
"""
grad = -y * sum(p_zeros) / (p_one * sum(pred)) + p_mask / sum(pred)

p_mask  = abs(y - 1)
p_zeros = p_mask * pred

y = label:      1D array of length N, one-hot 
p = prediction: 1D array of length N, float32 from 0 to 1
p_norm = normalized predictions
p_mask = prediction masks (see below)
"""
```

*What's happening?* Begin with a simple example to understand what `tf.GradientTape` is doing:

```py
w = tf.Variable([0.5, 0.1, 0.1])

with tf.GradientTape(persistent=True) as tape:
    f1 = w[0] + w[1]  # f = function
    f2 = w[0] / w[1]
    f3 = w[0] / (w[0] + w[1] + w[2])
print(tape.gradient(f1, w))  # [1.    1.  0.]
print(tape.gradient(f2, w))  # [10. -50.  0.]
print(tape.gradient(f3, w))  # [0.40816 -1.02040 -1.02040]
```

Let `w = [w1, w2, w3]`. Then:

```py
"""
grad = [df1/dw1, df1/dw2, df1/dw3]

grad1 = [d(w1 + w2)/w1, d(w1 + w2)/w2, d(w1 + w2)/w3] = [1, 1, 0]
grad2 = [d(w1 / w2)/w1, d(w1 / w2)/w2, d(w1 + w2)/w3] = [1/w2, -w1/w2^2, 0] = [10, -50, 0]
grad3 = [(w1 + w2)/K, - w2/K, -w3/K] = [0.40816 -1.02040 -1.02040] -- K = (w1 + w2 + w3)^2
"""
```

In other words, `tf.GradientTape` treats *each element* of the input tensor its differentiating against as a *variable*. This in mind, it suffices to implement categorical crossentropy via elementary `tf`functions then derive its derivative by hand and see if they agree. It's what I've done at the bottom code, with loss better explained in answer linked above.

---

**Formula explanation**:

`f3` above is the most insightful, as it's actually `pred_norm`; all we need now is to add a natural log, and handle two separate cases: grads for `y==1`, and for `y==0`; with a handy Wolf, derivatives can be computed in a flash. Adding more variables to denominator, we can see the following pattern:

- [`d(loss)/d(p_one)`](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=d%2Fdx+ln%28x+%2F+%28x+%2B+y+%2B+z%29%29) `= p_zeros / (p_one * sum(pred))`
- [`d(loss)/d(p_non_one)`](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=d%2Fdx+ln%28y+%2F+%28x+%2B+y+%2B+z%29%29) `= -1 / sum(pred)`

where `p_one` is `pred` where `label == 1`, `p_non_one` is any other `pred` element, and `p_zeros` is all `pred` elements except `p_one`. The code at bottom is simply an implementation of exactly this, using compact syntax.

---

**Explanation example**:

Suppose `label = [1, 0, 0]; pred = [.5, .1, .1]`. Below is `numpy_gradient`, step-by-step:

```py
p_mask == [0, 1, 1]  # effectively `label` "inverted", to exclude `p_one`
p_one  == .5         # pred where `label` == 1

## grad_zeros
p_mask / np.sum(pred) == [0, 1, 1] / (.5 + .1 + .1) = [0, 1/.7, 1/.7]

## grad_one
p_one  * np.sum(pred) == .5 * (.5 + .1 + .1) = .5 * .7 = .35
p_mask * pred         == [0, 1, 1] * [.5, .1, .1] = [0, .1, .1]
np.sum(p_mask * pred) == .2
label * np.sum(p_mask * pred) == .2 * [1, 0, 0] = [.2, 0, 0]

label * np.sum(p_mask * pred) / (p_one * np.sum(pred)) 
== [.2, 0, 0] / .35 = 0.57142854
```

Per above, we can see that the gradient is effectively divided into two computations: `grad_one`, and `grad_zeros`.

---

**Main idea**: understandably, that's a lot of detail, so here's the main idea: *every element* of `label` and `pred` affects `grad`, and loss is computed using `pred_norm`, not `pred`, and the **normalization step is backpropagated**. We can run a little visual to confirm this:

```py
labels = tf.constant([[1, 0, 0]],dtype=tf.float32)
grads = []
for i in np.linspace(0, 1, 100):
    logits = tf.Variable([[0.5, 0.1, i]], dtype=tf.float32)
    with tf.GradientTape(persistent=True) as tape:
        loss = tf.keras.losses.categorical_crossentropy(
              labels, logits, from_logits=False)  
    grads.append(tape.gradient(loss, logits))
grads = np.vstack(grads)
plt.plot(grads)
```

[image]

*Even though* only `logits[2]` is varied, `grads[1]` varies *exactly the same*. The explanation's clear from `grad_zeros` above, but more intuitively, categorical crossentropy *doesn't care* "how wrong" the zero-label predictions are individually, only *collectively* - because it only semi-directly computes loss from `pred[0]` (i.e. `pred[0] / sum(pred)`), which is normalized by all other `pred`. So whether `pred[1] == .9` and `pred[2] == .2` or vice versa, `p_norm` is exactly the same.

---

**Closing note**: derived formulas are intended for a 1D case for simplicity, and may not work for N-dimensional `labels` and `preds` tensors, but can be easily generalized.

---

**Numpy vs. tf.GradientTape**:

```py
def numpy_gradient(label, pred):
    p_mask = np.abs(label - 1)
    p_one  = pred[np.where(label==1)[0][0]]
    return p_mask / np.sum(pred) \
           - label * np.sum(p_mask * pred) / (p_one * np.sum(pred))

def gtape_gradient(label, pred):
    pred  = tf.Variable(pred)
    label = tf.Variable(label)

    with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
        loss = - tf.math.log(tf.reduce_sum(label * pred) / tf.reduce_sum(pred))
    return tape.gradient(loss, pred).numpy()
```

```py
label = np.array([1.,   0., 0. ])
pred  = np.array([0.5, 0.1, 0.1])
print(numpy_gradient(label, pred))
print(gtape_gradient(label, pred))

# [-0.57142854  1.4285713   1.4285713 ]  <-- 100% agreement
# [-0.57142866  1.4285713   1.4285713 ]  <-- 100% agreement
```

Comment: Normalization of pred is not expected by me if didn’t take a look at the source code at first. Great work!

Comment: @zihaozhihao Yeah, the inputs are normalized one way or the other no matter what, which is abstracted unless reading the source - and I find the Numpy backend a lot more understandable than raw `tf` code; when in doubt, Numpy. Fine question.