# How to calculate Categorical Cross-Entropy by hand?

Tags: python, tensorflow, artificial-intelligence

When I calculate Binary Crossentropy by hand I apply sigmoid to get probabilities, then use Cross-Entropy formula and mean the result:

```
logits = tf.constant([-1, -1, 0, 1, 2.])
labels = tf.constant([0, 0, 1, 1, 1.])

probs = tf.nn.sigmoid(logits)
loss = labels * (-tf.math.log(probs)) + (1 - labels) * (-tf.math.log(1 - probs))
print(tf.reduce_mean(loss).numpy()) # 0.35197204

cross_entropy = tf.keras.losses.BinaryCrossentropy(from_logits=True)
loss = cross_entropy(labels, logits)
print(loss.numpy()) # 0.35197204
```

How to calculate Categorical Cross-Entropy when `logits` and `labels` have different sizes?

```py
logits = tf.constant([[-3.27133679, -22.6687183, -4.15501118, -5.14916372, -5.94609261,
                       -6.93373299, -5.72364092, -9.75725174, -3.15748906, -4.84012318],
                      [-11.7642536, -45.3370094, -3.17252636, 4.34527206, -17.7164974,
                      -0.595088899, -17.6322937, -2.36941719, -6.82157373, -3.47369862],
                      [-4.55468369, -1.07379043, -3.73261762, -7.08982277, -0.0288562477, 
                       -5.46847963, -0.979336262, -3.03667569, -3.29502845, -2.25880361]])
labels = tf.constant([2, 3, 4])

loss_object = tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True,
                                                            reduction='none')
loss = loss_object(labels, logits)
print(loss.numpy()) # [2.0077195  0.00928135 0.6800677 ]
print(tf.reduce_mean(loss).numpy()) # 0.8990229
```

I mean how can I get the same result (`[2.0077195  0.00928135 0.6800677 ]`) by hand?

@OverLordGoldDragon answer is correct. In `TF 2.0` it looks like this:

```
loss_object = tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(
    from_logits=True, reduction='none')
loss = loss_object(labels, logits)
print(f'{loss.numpy()}\n{tf.math.reduce_sum(loss).numpy()}')

one_hot_labels = tf.one_hot(labels, 10)

preds = tf.nn.softmax(logits)
preds /= tf.math.reduce_sum(preds, axis=-1, keepdims=True)
loss = tf.math.reduce_sum(tf.math.multiply(one_hot_labels, -tf.math.log(preds)), axis=-1)
print(f'{loss.numpy()}\n{tf.math.reduce_sum(loss).numpy()}')
# [2.0077195  0.00928135 0.6800677 ]
# 2.697068691253662
# [2.0077198  0.00928142 0.6800677 ]
# 2.697068929672241
```

For language models:

```
vocab_size = 9
seq_len = 6
batch_size = 2

labels = tf.reshape(tf.range(batch_size*seq_len), (batch_size,seq_len)) # (2, 6)
logits = tf.random.normal((batch_size,seq_len,vocab_size)) # (2, 6, 9)

loss_object = tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(
    from_logits=True, reduction='none')
loss = loss_object(labels, logits)
print(f'{loss.numpy()}\n{tf.math.reduce_sum(loss).numpy()}')

one_hot_labels = tf.one_hot(labels, vocab_size)

preds = tf.nn.softmax(logits)
preds /= tf.math.reduce_sum(preds, axis=-1, keepdims=True)
loss = tf.math.reduce_sum(tf.math.multiply(one_hot_labels, -tf.math.log(preds)), axis=-1)
print(f'{loss.numpy()}\n{tf.math.reduce_sum(loss).numpy()}')
# [[1.341706  3.2518263 2.6482694 3.039099  1.5835983 4.3498387]
#  [2.67237   3.3978183 2.8657475       nan       nan       nan]]
# nan
# [[1.341706  3.2518263 2.6482694 3.039099  1.5835984 4.3498387]
#  [2.67237   3.3978183 2.8657475 0.        0.        0.       ]]
# 25.1502742767334
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`SparseCategoricalCrossentropy` is `CategoricalCrossentropy` that takes *integer* labels as opposed to *one-hot*. Example from [source code](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r2.0/tensorflow/python/keras/losses.py#L473), the two below are equivalent:

```py
scce = tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy()
cce = tf.keras.losses.CategoricalCrossentropy()

labels_scce = K.variable([[0, 1, 2]]) 
labels_cce  = K.variable([[1,    0,  0], [0,    1,  0], [0,   0,   1]])
preds       = K.variable([[.90,.05,.05], [.50,.89,.60], [.05,.01,.94]])

loss_cce  = cce(labels_cce,   preds, from_logits=False)
loss_scce = scce(labels_scce, preds, from_logits=False)
```

```py
with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    sess.run([loss_cce, loss_scce])

print(K.get_value(loss_cce))
print(K.get_value(loss_scce))
# [0.10536055  0.8046684  0.0618754]
# [0.10536055  0.8046684  0.0618754]
```

As to how to do it 'by hand', we can refer to the [Numpy backend](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/985521ee7050df39f9c06f53b54e17927bd1e6ea/keras/backend/numpy_backend.py#L333):

```py
np_labels = K.get_value(labels_cce)
np_preds  = K.get_value(preds)

losses = []
for label, pred in zip(np_labels, np_preds):
    pred /= pred.sum(axis=-1, keepdims=True)
    losses.append(np.sum(label * -np.log(pred), axis=-1, keepdims=False))
print(losses)
# [0.10536055  0.8046684  0.0618754]
```

- `from_logits = True`: `preds` is model output *before* passing it into `softmax` (so  we pass it  into softmax)
- `from_logits = False`: `preds` is model output *after* passing it into `softmax` (so we skip this step)

So in summary, to compute it by hand:

1. Convert integer labels to one-hot labels
2. If preds are model outputs *before* softmax, we compute their softmax
3. `pred /= ...` *normalizes* predictions before computing logs; this way, high-probab. preds on zero-labels *penalize* correct predictions on one-labels. If `from_logits = False`, this step is *skipped*, since `softmax` does the normalization. See [this snippet](https://pastebin.com/r5K7ZaYw). [Further reading](https://gombru.github.io/2018/05/23/cross_entropy_loss/)
4. For each observation / sample, compute element-wise negative `log` (base e) *only where* `label==1`
5. Take mean of losses for all the observations

---

Lastly, the mathematical formula for categorical crossentropy is:

[image]

- `i` iterates over `N` observations
- `c` iterates over `C` classes
- **1** is the [indicator function](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Indicator_function) - here, like binary crossentropy, except operates on length-`C` vectors
- `p_model [y_i \in C_c]` - predicted probability of observation `i` belonging to class `c`

Comment: thank you. I tried to repeat your code in `TF 2.0`: I got the first and the third label loss the same, but the second is wrong. Do you know why that is? I updated the post.

Comment: @dereks Missed a line when pasting, my bad - see updated answer

Comment: @dereks They're separate - `batch_size` is the number of _independent sequences_ (e.g. sentences) you feed to the model , `vocab_size` is your number of characters/words (feature dimension), `seq_len` is # of characters/words per sequence (sentence/word). Whether `vocab_size` holds words/chars is up to model design - some models are _word-level_, others _character-level_ - regardless, this is a separate question.

Comment: Yes, thank you. I deleted my previous comment when I got how it works.

Comment: Sorry to bother you, in Binary we compute `p(-log(q)) + (1-p)(-log(1-q))`: the distance from 1 to target plus the distance from 0 to target. But in Cathegorical case we have only `p(-log(q))`, so for every zero label the loss is 0. Why don't we compute `(1-p)(-log(1-q))` for Cathegorical Crossentropy?

Comment: @dereks Fair question, should've explained originally -- updated (under summary). Not the entire explanation, you may want to read up on [categorical crossentropy](https://gombru.github.io/2018/05/23/cross_entropy_loss/) - but does show that zero-label predictions aren't simply 'lost'

Comment: Do you have a reference for the mathematical formula for categorical crossentropy ?

Comment: @OverLordGoldDragon You mentioned that the `from_logits=False` does not normalize the input. In your manual calculation, you are normalizing the input. So how come the result computed from TF's CategoryCrossEntropy is same as the manual calculation?